Dropping a flexible bag on a spring balance
The following problem has been troubling, me for quite some time, the statement of the question is as follows,

When a flexible bag filled with sand is dropped on the pan of a spring balance from a height of $h = 4\hspace{1mm}\text{cm}$ above the pan, pointer of the balance suddenly shoots to a reading of $m_1 = 6.0\hspace{1mm}\text{kg}$ and after several oscillations finally settles to a reading $m_2 = 2.0\hspace{1mm}\text{kg}$. If the force constant of the spring is $k = 1.5\hspace{1mm}\text{kN/m}$ and dry friction is absent, find the mass of the pan. Assume acceleration of free fall $g = 10\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{m/s^2}.$

When solving the problem, I assumed that the spring balance had been calibrated in such a way that weight of the pan corresponds to zero reading on the balance. After checking my answer, one of the hints given in my textbook is the same, so I believe this is correct.
Now say the mass of the flexible bag is $m_0$, them from the problem itself we know that
$$m_0 = m_2.$$
The velocity of the bag + pan after the first make contact and can be calculated using conservation of momentum as follows,
$$m_0\sqrt{2gh} = (m_0 + m_p)v$$
$$v = \frac{m_0}{m_0 + m_p}\sqrt{2gh},$$
where $m_p$ is the mass of the pan.
Since after everything has happened the two are at rest, the change in kinetic energy of the bag+pan is,
\begin{align}
\Delta KE &= \frac{1}{2}(m_0 + m_p)\frac{m_0^2}{(m_0 + m_p)^2}2gh \\
&= \frac{m_2^2gh}{m_2 + m_p}.
\end{align}
Now this must be the change in potential energy of the spring balance, whose spring constant is given. So we have,
$$\Delta KE = \frac{k}{2}(x_f^2 + x_i^2).$$
We observe that,
$$x_f = (m_2 + m_p)g/k \quad \text{ and } \quad x_i = \frac{m_p g}{k}.$$
Plugging these two things back into the equation we obtained earlier, where we equate change in potential energy to change in kinetic energy, we obtain that, after solving some quadratics $$m_p = 2\hspace{1mm}\text{kg}.$$
Now the thing is: this is the correct answer in my textbook, however the answer is given in the following form:
\begin{align}
m_p &= \frac{2km_2^2h}{m_1(m_1-2m_2)g} - m_2 \\ &= 2\hspace{1mm}\text{kg}.
\end{align}
When I solve my equations, I do not get this form, for the answer.
Is my solution wrong? If so, where is the conceptual error (as I cannot spot it), or is the textbook wrong? Any help on this problem would be highly appreciated.

As long as your answer is correct as far as the final number which counts in a test, I would not worry. One cannot go into all the possible ways a problem can be solved, imo.

@annav nice, but i posted this problem not for that reason, there is a possibility that my solution might not be right and just happens to numerically match up with the solution. The point of solving physics problems should not be to just get the answer to match up with the test, it should be to understand the world better.

This site does not have your objective, understanding the world better. It is a site which answers main stream physics questions. Homework like questions are discouraged, and usually the question would be closed.Your question then falls in the category of homework questions, "do calculations for me" and is liable to closure.

Try to solve using impulse. According to me the 6kg reading is due to the impulsive force provided by the bag and pan together. By definition impulse is a large force acting for a very short period of time.
Therefore the equations can be framed as
Considering mass of pan= m2
Mass of sand bag = m1
Though impulse theoreum
Impulse= change in momentum
6g= m1(vfinal-√0.8) + m2(vfinal) - 1st equation
Both pan and sand bag would have same final velcities
√0.8 = √2g 0.04 (given)
Through work energy theorem
Work done by gravity + work done by spring force = change in kinetic energy
Therefore
(M1 + M2)gx - 1/2kx^2 = 0
Here x is the compression of spring - 2nd equation
For 3rd equation consider the final FBD(free body diagram)  of the pan + sand bag
Normal= (m1+m2)g - kx
Here normal reaction is considered to be 2g.
Through conservation of linear momenta
M1√0.8 = [m1+m2]vfinal
Since there are four variables as stated
M1
M2
X
V final
And four equations. The question could thus be solved.
If you encounter any mistake in my solution please write it to me.
Thanks
Yash
